# How to scale push notifications in Firebase Cloud functions for this use case?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

In my app, I am sending push notifications to the followers of a user when that user creates a new post. As you can see in the code below, I have some additional settings that I need to query from each follower's profile to get their push token and check for some additional notification settings. I am afraid that this query of each user's profile might become a bottleneck if a user has a large number of followers i.e. 1000.

What is the best way to approach this?

```
// The cloud function to trigger when a post is created
exports.newPost = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postId}').onCreate(event => {

    const postId = event.params.postId;
    const post = event.data.val();
    const userId = post.author;

    let tokens = [];
    let promises = [];

    return admin.database().ref(`/followers/${userId}`).once('value', (followers) => {
        followers.forEach((f) => {
            let follower = f.key;
            promises.push(
                admin.database().ref(`users/${follower}`).once('value')
            );
        });
    })
    .then(() => {
        return Promise.all(promises).then((users) => {
            users.forEach((user) => {
                const userDetails = user.val();
                if (userDetails.post_notifications) {
                    if(userDetails.push_id != null) {
                        tokens.push(userDetails.push_id);
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    })
    .then(() => {
        if (tokens.length > 0) {
            const payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: 'New Post!',
                    body: 'A new post has been created'
                }
            };
            // Send notifications to all tokens.
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
        }
    });
})
```

**EDIT:**

We have thought about using topics. But we are not sure how we can still have our customized notifications settings working with topics. Here's our dilemma.

We have multiple actions that can create notifications and we provide individual switches for each type of notification in the app so a user can select which type of notifications they want to switch off.

Let's say when User A follows User B. We can subscribe User A to "User B's topic" so whenever User B performs an action which sends out notifications to his/her followers, I can send send out notifications to users subscribed to "User B topic".

Because we have multiple notification switches in the app and when user A changes his/her settings that they do not want notifications for new posts but still want other types of notifications from the users he/she follows, we have not been able to figure out how we can use topics in this case.

Comment: cant you use topics?

Comment: @PeterHaddad I've edited the question and explained why we haven't used topics. Maybe you can elaborate more based on what I wrote about using topics.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using tokens, you can use topics for this. So lets say a user started following someone, then he will register to that topic.

Lets say he followed someone called "Peter", then you can execute this:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Peter");
```

Now if you have this database:

```
posts
  postid
     postdetails: detailshere
     author: Peter
```

then using `onCreate()`:

```
exports.newPost = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postId}').onCreate(event => {
const postId = event.params.postId;
const post = event.data.val();
const authorname = post.author;
const details=post.postdetails;

const payload = {
 data: {
    title:userId,
    body: details,
    sound: "default"
     },
  };

 const options = {
    priority: "high",
     timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
    };

return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(authorname, payload, options);
 });
```

You can use this, everytime the author creates a new post, `onCreate()` is triggered then you can add the details of the post and the author name in the notification (if you want) and `sendToTopic()` will send it to all users subscribed to the topic that is the `authorname` (ex: Peter)

After your edit, I think you want the user to be unsubscribed from a topic, but stay subscribed to other topics, then you have to use the admin sdk for this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/manage-topic-subscriptions

Using the admin sdk you can unsubscribe the user also from a topic, a simple example:

```
 // These registration tokens come from the client FCM SDKs.
var registrationTokens = [
 'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_1',
 // ...
 'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_n'
];

// Unsubscribe the devices corresponding to the registration tokens from
// the topic.
admin.messaging().unsubscribeFromTopic(registrationTokens, topic)
.then(function(response) {
  // See the MessagingTopicManagementResponse reference documentation
  // for the contents of response.
  console.log('Successfully unsubscribed from topic:', response);
 })
 .catch(function(error) {
   console.log('Error unsubscribing from topic:', error);
  });
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned about why we haven't used topics in the original question. It's tricky to use use topics as we have user specific notification settings we need to consider.

Comment: @Sunny When a user clicks on "don't receive notification from this topic" then using the admin sdk you and unsubscribe him. Add in the database a field called "subscribed" if it changes to false, then onWrite will be triggered and he will be unsubscribed